# crontab email send

Tags: cron

Cron example: `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /html/includes/CRON.php > /html/includes/logs/CRON_LOG.txt`

This is how everything look like, but how add an option **not** to send me an email's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably still receiving emails because you're only redirecting `stdout`, but not `stderr`. To redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`, use

> */1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /html/includes/CRON.php > /html/includes/logs/CRON_LOG.txt 2> /dev/null

(or wherever you want `stderr` to be redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

You might define MAILTO in the crontab.

If MAILTO is defined but empty MAILTO="", no mail will be sent.

kind of

```
MAILTO="" 
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /html/includes/CRON.php > /html/includes/logs/CRON_LOG.txt
```

Comment: Well, i don't have access to my shell, everythink done via web. (plesk panel): http://www.hosting.com/support/plesk/crontab  It give's only one line for code, so...

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the top of the cron file

```
MAILTO=""
```